# Deserialize xml to complex objects

Tags: c#, xml, object, deserialization, .net-core

I am able to bind simple bits of information out of the feed like Id, but attempting to parse out complex objects always end up null. What am I doing wrong in my mapping?

Feed

```
[XmlRoot("feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class Feed
{
    [XmlElement("author")]
    Author Author { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("entry")]
    List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Author

```
[XmlType("author")]
public class Author
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Entry

```
[XmlType("entry")]
public class Entry
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("published")]
    DateTime Published { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("updated")]
    DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing

```
        using (Stream stream = res.GetResponseStream())
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Feed));
            feed = (Feed)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
```

Comment: Show input xml.

Comment: See [Syndication Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication(v=vs.110).aspx). Use [SyndicationFeed Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.110).aspx) to work with RSS.

Comment: Project is using .net core, input xml is blogspot atom feed like 
http://cellularscale.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect "feed" class definition bit.

try the below way and see if it works.

1. Declare your "Author" class and List class `public`.
2. Try constructing Author and List in the constructor as shown in below code.

   ```
   [XmlRoot("feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
   public class Feed
   {
         //ADD A CONSTRUCTOR AND CREATE LIST AND AUTHOR
         public Feed()
         {
            Author1 = new Author();
            Entries = new List<Entry>();

         }

         [XmlElement("author")]
         public Author Author1 { get; set; }

         [XmlElement("entry")]
         public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

         [XmlElement("id")]
         public string Id { get; set; } 
   }
   ```

Comment: Argh! Adding public to Author and Entries in Feed fixed the problem. Thank you